# Converting Date to string and vice versa returns error message

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-update, case

I am trying to run the following query but I don't know why it's not working:

```
UPDATE Table 
SET [Column] = (CASE 
                   WHEN ISNULL(CAST([Column_DATETIME] AS VARCHAR(50)), '') = '' 
                      THEN 'NON'
                   WHEN [Column_DATETIME] > CAST('2020-01-01' AS DATETIME) 
                      THEN 'OUI'
                   ELSE 'NON' 
                END)
```

It returns the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Which logic are you trying to implement?

Comment: @GMB if datetime column is blank or null then another column should have the value 'non' if it's superior than 2020-01-01 then 'oui' if neither then 'non'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to try and compare the value in `column_datetime` to a literal date, and set a flag accordingly.

If that column is of a `date`-like datatype:

```
update mytable set col = 
    case when column_datetime > '20200101' then 'OUI' else 'NON' end
```

Everything after the literal date is set to "OUI", and everything else is set to "NO" (that includes null values).

If that's a string, it depends on the format. Sometimes string operations work, but the safer option is to convert:

```
update mytable set col = 
    case when try_cast(column_datetime as datetime) > '2020-01-01' then 'OUI' else 'NON' end
```

Strings that cannot be converted are silently turned to `null` values (that would include the empty string, if any), and end up in group "NON".